# Angular 2: Custom service is undefiend in another service

Tags: angular

I wrote an HttpInterceptor and I want to use a NotificationService in it. but the NotificationService is undefined in the httpInterceptor. is there anything missed.

**HttpInterceptor.ts**

```
...<imports>...
export class HttpInterceptor extends Http {


  constructor(
    backend: ConnectionBackend,
    defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
    private notificationService: NotificationService
  ) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  private beforeRequest(): void {
       this.notificationService.showPreloader(); //this.notificationService is undefined
  }
  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    this.beforeRequest();
    return super.get(HttpInterceptor.getFullUrl(url), HttpInterceptor.requestOptions(options))
  }
}
```

**NotificationService.ts**

```
export class NotificationService {
   showPreloader() {
      console.log('preloader show!');
   }
}
```

**AppModule.ts**

```
providers: [ModalModule, NotificationService, {
   provide: HttpInterceptor,
   useFactory: httpFactory,
   deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
}],
export function httpFactory(backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, notificationService: NotificationService) {
  return new HttpInterceptor(backend, defaultOptions, notificationService);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed one dependency for your factory:

```
deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, NotificationService]
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                       add this
```

Comment: Can you create a plunker? Or add the code where you use `notification`

Comment: The error `_co.notification is undefined` seems is coming from your template